# sizeof function keeps failing on extern array

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am facing a problem as explained below

I have some C files

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    int x = sizeof(a);
    printf("size = %d\n", x);
}
```

`header.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a[];
```

and `header.c`

```
#include "header.h"

int a[] = {1, 21, 3};
```

Que 1: Is this extern declaration correct?

Que 2: If yes, I am getting an error on compilation as

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5:19: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘int[]’
     int x = sizeof(a);
                   ^
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: `incomplete type`.....try googling it. :)

Comment: Note: `sizeof` is **not** a function, it is an *operator*.

Answer (score 2):

In `main` the compiler knows that `a` is an array of `int` because of the `extern int a[];` declaration in `header.h`.

But it doesn't know it's size because the the declaration from which the size can be deduced (`int a[] = {1, 21, 3};`) is not visible in `main.c`, because it's in `header.c` which is totally unrelated to `main.c`; you can compile `main.c` even if `header.c` does not exist (at least if you remove the bogous `sizeof`).

There is no way to get the size of the `a` array directly from within `main.c` 
But you can make a function in `header.c` that tells you the size of the `a` array:

**header.c**

```
#include "header.h"

int a[] = {1, 21, 3};

int GetSizeofA()
{
   return sizeof a;
}
```

**header.h**

```
extern int a[];
int GetSizeofA();
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    int x = GetSizeofA();
    printf("size = %d\n", x);
}
```

BTW: there is no need to `#include <stdio.h>` in `header.h`.